# Dataset in html

Tags: html, asp.net, dataset

I am using asp.net and i would like to define the elements of a dataset in my html code.
The problem is when i attempt to use:

```
<%@Using namespace="System.Data" %>
```

this is giving me an error

also

I am using

```
foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
          {.....}
```

DataSet ds is obtained from an sql query. I don't believe to have any tables so is the above code ok?

Comment: You say 'this is giving me an error'. Exactly what error you are receiving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to import a namespace in the aspx page, try this:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>
```

If you're more specific about your error, we can help you there too!

Answer (score 2):

If ds was defined in the code-behind for it to be available in the .aspx side of things you must declare it as protected, rather than private.